# Working with JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on an old website that uses the Ext framework. It has a huge .js file at its core. I'm not a front-end web guy, I usually write the server and service side code, so I'm unfamiliar with getting heavy with JavaScript in Visual Studio.

In this file, there's this snippet:

```
...

// private
onDestroy : function(){
    if(this.manager){
        this.manager.unregister(this);
    }
    Ext.Window.superclass.onDestroy.call(this);
},

...
```

How do I find the 'manager' member there? I can't F12 to it and there's no combobox full of members at the top of the editor.

Is this just how it is with JavaScript? Is it because VS has poor support? Is it something to do with the way the project/files are setup?

Please don't mention alternative IDEs, or if you do, don't pass opinion on them that might get us in trouble with the SO police. Woop, woop.

Comment: Are you trying to see content of 'manager' object - its properties or methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I gave it a while and no one piped up so, from what I've just seen on //build/ 2013, Visual Studio 2012 is pretty crap with JavaScript and its much improved in 2013, including the 'combobox full of members' at the top, CoffeeScript support and some other recent ECMAScript change support.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 with at least ReSharper 7 is a slightly better ride with JavaScript - you can F12 on members and jump to the source file.

Comment: I've been getting into javascript lately and tried some ide's. None of them are really good at completing code, I guess it has to do with the loosely typed nature of JS. I still prefer VS2012 above anything else I tried.. (and coming from a java/c++ background I've got a really hard time getting into the JS way of doing things, books say you'll fall in love with it after a while, but I dont seem to get it)

Comment: Thanks guys, I suspect to feel the same way. Very interested by TypeScript, I find static typing makes me faster, train on rails. Anyway, better not get into a conversation here.